# Sharing function between classes

Tags: c++, oop

I have three classes which each store their own array of double values. To populate the arrays I use a fairly complex function, lets say `foo()`, which takes in several parameters and calculates the appropriate values for the array.

Each of my three classes uses the same function with only minor adjustments (i.e. the input parameters vary slightly). Each of the classes is actually quite similar although they each perform separate logic when retrieving the values of the array.

So I am wondering how should I 'share' the function so that all classes can use it, without having to duplicate the code?

I was thinking of creating a base class which contained the function `foo()` and a virtual `get()` method. My three classes could then inherit this base class. Alternatively, I was also thinking perhaps a global function was the way to go? maybe putting the function into a namespace?

Comment: Avoid global as much as you can. Go for an OO solution as you described it, with a base class.

Comment: Both approaches you have suggested are viable. Which one is more appropriate depends a lot on details we don't have. Is there more commonality between the three classes? If so, a common base class might be appropriate. Is foo() a meaningful operation that might be useful to classes unrelated to the current three? If so, make it a global function in an appropriate namespace. I would suggest you use whichever abstraction feels more natural when you think about the concepts of your program. That is kind of vague but this is the kind of gut decision you need to make all the time when programming.

Answer (score 2):

If the classes have nothing in common besides this `foo()` function, it is silly to put it in a base class; make it a free function instead.  C++ is not Java.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying data of the class is the same (Array of doubles), considering using a single class and overloading the constructor, or just use 3 different functions:

> void PopulateFromString(const string&)
>   void PopulateFromXml(...)
>   void PopulateFromInteger(...)

If the data or the behavior is different in each class type, then your solution of base class is good.

You can also define a function in the same namespace as your classes as utility function, if it has nothing to do with specific class behavior (Polymorphism). Bjarne StroupStroup recommends this method by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring of a function in base class sounds the most appropriate solution. Not sure if you need virtual "get" though, instead just declare the array in the base class and provide access method(s) for descendants.

More complex part is "the input parameters vary slightly". If parameters differ by type only then you may write a template function. If difference is more significant than the only solution I see is splitting main function into several logic blocks and using these blocks in descendant classes to perform final result.

Answer (score 0):

If your classes are quite similar, you could create a template class with three different implementations that has the function `foo<T>()`

Answer (score 0):

Implement that function in base class. If these classes are similar as you say, they should be derived from one base class anyway! If there are several functions like foo(), it might be reasonable in some cases to combine them into another class which is utilized by/with your classes.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of this answer, I am assuming the classes you have are not common in any other outwards way;  they may load the same data, but they are providing different interfaces.

There are two possible situations here, and you haven't told us which one it is.  It could be more like

```
void foo(double* arr, size_t size) {
    // Some specific code (that probably just does some preparation)
    // Lots of generic code
    // ...
    // Some more specific code (cleanup?)
}
```

or something similar to

```
void foo(double* arr, size_t size) {
    // generic_code();
    // ...
    // specific_code();
    // generic_code();
    // ...
}
```

In the first case, the generic code may very well be easy to put into a separate function, and then making a base class doesn't make much sense: you'll probably be inheriting from it privately, and you should prefer composition over private inheritance unless you have a good reason to.  You could put the new function in its own class if it benefits from it, but it's not strictly necessary.  Whether you put it in a namespace or not depends on how you're organising your code.

The second case is trickier, and in that case I would advise polymorphism.  However, you don't seem to need runtime polymorphism for this, and so you could just as well do it compile-time.  Using the fact that this is C++, you can use CRTP:

```
template<typename IMPL>
class MyBase {
    void foo(double* arr, size_t size) {
        // generic code
        // ...
        double importantResult = IMPL::DoALittleWork(/* args */);
        // more generic code
        // ...
    }
};

class Derived : MyBase<Derived> {
    static double DoALittleWork(/* params */) {
        // My specific stuff
        return result;
    }
};
```

This gives you the benefit of code organisation and saves you some virtual functions.  On the other hand, it does make it slightly less clear what functions need to be implemented (although [the error messages are not that bad](http://codepad.org/dxhF1kXx)).

I would only go with the second route if making a new function (possibly within a new class) would clearly be uglier.  If you're parsing different formats as Andrey says, then having a parser object (that would be polymorphic) passed in would be even nicer as it would allow you to mock things with less trouble, but you haven't given enough details to say for sure.